# How to send data outside of the browser sandbox?

Tags: java, web

I'm creating a (vaadin) `web application` with java. I will also have the requirement to send data from within the client browser to a local application of the user.

The user clicks a specific button, and the data is pushed to a local application on his machine, eg through a socket or whatever native OS functions. I will only have to support applications on `windows`.

Question: how could I achieve this? Of course the `browser` itself is a sandbox, so I cannot just get the data out of it directly.

Is there any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is best to approach the problem from the other direction: have the locally running application (did you mention which application you use or which programming language it is written in ?) subscribe to the web application.

There are lots of techniques that allow your application to be signalled by the web application and have data pushed afterwards: mqtt, websockets, xmpp, ...

Comment: I'm creating a `vaadin` application as mentioned above. Thus, it is a java web application on a webservice, and clients will connect only using their browser. I can NOT run the application itself on the client machines locally. They must connect to the app using the browser, but they also require some data being send to a local application (that I don't develop myself).

Comment: The techniques mentioned above would allow you to have the browser send data to the application, but only if you had access to the sourcecode. I think you need to be more specific what kind of data you want to send and what the application does and is technically based on.